# simple multi line chart with D3

Tags: d3.js, coffeescript

http://jsfiddle.net/ytvka/4/

I know this one has been asked before but I've not been able to use those examples to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I want to create a simple 6 point, 3 series chart with data that looks like:

```
data = [
  {"key":"D78","date":"2013-09-23T17:26:21.258Z","value":1.25}, 
  {"key":"D78","date":"2013-09-23T17:28:21.258Z","value":2.25},
  {"key":"R71","date":"2013-09-23T17:26:21.258Z","value":2.45},
  {"key":"R71","date":"2013-09-23T17:28:21.258Z","value":2.85},
  {"key":"X44","date":"2013-09-23T17:26:21.258Z","value":3.87},
  {"key":"X44","date":"2013-09-23T17:28:21.258Z","value":3.87}
]
```

Nothing exciting there. What I'd ideally like to do is make a 3-series line chart out of this data.

```
svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g")

x = d3.time.scale().range([ 0, width ])
y = d3.scale.linear().range([ height, 0 ])
format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")

valueLine = d3.svg.line().interpolate("basis")
  .x((d) ->
    console.log format.parse(d.date)
    x(format.parse(d.date))
  )
  .y((d) ->
    console.log d.value
    y d.value
  )

  svg.append("path").attr("class", "line")
    .attr "d", valueLine(u.where(data, key: "X44"))
```

Which generates SVG: `<path class="line" d="M137998238125800,-287L137998250125800,-287"></path>`

This code just pulls out one of the series using lodash. Problem is: nothing on the screen. It runs through and grabs the value but there's no lines. I'm finding that existing examples are either complex and not well explained (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955) or missing key parts (http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-more-than-one-line-to-graph-in.html).

1. What's wrong with my code?
2. How can I add in the other series (R71, D78)?
3. Is there a good tutorial of this out there that has complete code and walks through all the steps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first point is at (137998238125800,-287) pixel coordinate, which is far away from the visible screen area. You don't use the selectAll/enter pattern which is at the core of D3. So you should start with this fundamental [tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html), then probably the code example you mention will make more sense:

```
var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

  city.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
```

Comment: That first point looks suspiciously like a js date, current date is 1380039691123 right now. So something must be happening there. That looks like a pretty good tutorial, i'll check it out. The d3noob site that I linked didn't use `enter` so I question its importance.

Comment: Initially when I read the above comment, I thought you must be mistaken about the d3noob example not using `enter`. But you're completely right! Here's a link to a slight variation as a live version http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8603837. Biovisualize is completely right in recommending [Mikes tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/circle.html) as it is a masterclass in doing d3.js correctly.